# mqtt create certificate to authentificate clients at the server

Tags: node.js, ssl, openssl, mqtt

I did set up a mqtt broker and want that mqtt clients authentificate themself with a certificate/key at the server. I found [this tutorial here](http://www.steves-internet-guide.com/creating-and-using-client-certificates-with-mqtt-and-mosquitto/) to create certificates for that and followed all steps. At the end I saw that there was'nt any code to generate the server.crt files so I just redid the steps but replaced 'client' with 'server'. (Edit: I saw that there is a tutorial for that but it is just the same as the client cert. So I did it right.)

I did set up the broker with those certificates and did the same with the client.

But when I try to connect to the broker with my program, I get this error message:

```
Error: unsupported certificate purpose
    at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (node:_tls_wrap:1530:34)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (node:_tls_wrap:944:8)
    at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (node:_tls_wrap:725:12) {
  code: 'INVALID_PURPOSE'
}
```

I don't know what went wrong in that tutorial but it isn't working anymore. Any Idea what is wrong in the tutorial?

---

Edit: I did create the CA cert a buit differently. This is the command I used to generate it:

```
openssl req -x509 -nodes -newkey rsa:2048 -days 3650 -sha256 \
  -keyout ca.key -out ca.crt -reqexts SAN -extensions SAN \
  -subj '/CN=Broker Cert' \
  -config <(cat /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf; printf "[SAN]\nsubjectAltName=IP:172.27.224.1")
```

Comment: Out of interest what OS/Platform are you running all this on. The 2 issues you've run into I would not expect with any of the normal distros, it feels like you have a custom OpenSSL library that has all the alerts/errors/warnings turned up to 11.

Comment: @hardillb I am currently trying to run the mqtt client on windows 10 with an node.js script that uses the mqtt module. The cert's where created on a normal installation of debian buster.

Answer (score 0):

The message is because OpenSSl says your client certificate is missing the flag that says it can be used to identify a client.

These flags (there are actually 2 sets of flags, but I'm simplifying a little here) are part of the x509 spec and the 2 that are useful in this case are going to be:

1. `serverAuth` which is used by servers to attest to their identity
2. `clientAuth` which is used by clients to attest to their identity

Running

```
openssl x509 -noout -ext extendedKeyUsage < client.crt
```

Should print out what extensions are included in your certificate.

Steve's instuctions do not explicitly create v3 x509 certificates so do not include the extendedKeyUsage flags, but this might also be down to the default openssl.cnf that you have in your environment.

You may do better looking for a HOWTO on how to build a full Certificate Authority which includes writing a `openssl.cnf` file. e.g. https://jamielinux.com/docs/openssl-certificate-authority/introduction.html

Comment: It says that the cert doesn't have any extensions. What would be the right command to use for generating the client cert so it can be used the way I want?